# ASP.NET MultiView Can't Find its View

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, multiview

We have a custom control built for our Umbraco Site and this week I had to add another form to our custom form user control.

However, it decides to not get discoverable by Umbraco, throwing this error:

> The view null cannot be found inside MultiViewOptions, the ActiveView must be a View control directly inside a MultiView

I took the user control and added it to a blank asp.net site and it works correctly.

but on Umbraco it does not.

Further more I added a clause to call it directly if it couldn't be found by the normal way we are doing it and again it says its not there.

I'm totally out of ideas as to how this view can't be located.

Any kind of help will save me from my sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and it was a moment of dumbness for me.

I failed to upload the html portion of the user control only uploading the dll portion, which now after taking the weekend to rest makes a lot of sense.

my form is now visible.